# Is there a catchable event trigger where is fired when I get a IIS error that needs to restart the application pool?

Tags: windows, iis-7.5

Due a error that frequently occurs in an application and only is solved when its application pool is restarted, I'm trying to know if is possible to bind a trigger in order to do a treatment by command line. Sure that an alternative of automatic restart would be pretty welcome as well. Although I already has identified the error reason, I'll use temporarily the alternative above.

Comment: Does the error condition write something to the event log? In that case you can just attach an event trigger and have it recycle the apppool automatically

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I took a look in the event log but I still haven't caught the error once that it is intermittent. Can you explain with other details a "how to" of your given suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the error condition causes an event to get logged in an event log, you can attach a task to such an event - simply set up the task to recycle the apppool:

1. Go to the event viewer and find an instance of the event/error
2. Right-click and select "Attach Task To This Event..."
3. A task scheduler wizard pops up - click next until the "Start a Program" page appears
4. Set up the task to run `%systemroot%\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe` with the following arguments: `recycle apppool "[Name of Application Pool]"`
5. On the last page of the wizard, check "Open the Properties page when I click finish" option.
6. Configure the task to run with highest privileges.

Next time the event gets logged, the app pool is automatically recycled

Comment: seems the future accepted answer. I have to await the intermittent error occur again and try to found in the event viewer to attach the task. Have you some idea where can I will find this log? The error occurs due a Dll fault of the PHP.

Comment: I haven't confirmed whether the server has been performed the task as expected due the  event didn't fired, however I'll click as the accept answer once it seems a valid way.